# Vue3.js and Pinia: Why is my store state undefined in VueDevtools?

Tags: vue.js, state, undefined, pinia, vue-devtools

I am using Vue 3 with Pinia ^2.0.14. I'm importing Pinia into the app in `main.ts` like so:

```
import { createPinia } from 'pinia'
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

const pinia = createPinia()

const app = createApp(App).use(pinia).mount('#app')
```

I'm creating the store `language.ts` like so:

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'

export const useLanguageStore = defineStore({
  id: 'language',
  state: () => ({
    language: 'English',
    languages: ['English', 'Spanish'],
  }),
})
```

and using it in `LanguageDropdown.vue` like so:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { useLanguageStore } from '@/store/language.ts'

const languageStore = useLanguageStore()
</script>

<template>
  <select
    v-model="languageStore.language">
    <option
      v-for="language in languageStore.languages"
      :key="language"
      :value="language"
    >
      {{ language }}
    </option>
  </select>
</template>
```

The code works as expected, but in the Vue devtools inspector `languageStore.language`, `languageStore.languages`, and `language.state` are `undefined`. Why would that be?

[screen shot of Vue devtools inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZrEB.png)

Answer (score 0):

I found a away to solve it, though I think its not perfect

```php
// should use computed
const languages = computed(() => languageStore.languages )
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: I edited this, to turn it into something of an answer (see above). Please avoid asking questions in what is supposed to be an answering post. The post in initial state was risking being flagged as not-an-answer.

Answer (score -3):

Maybe you need correct install pinia in your App

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import { createPinia } from 'pinia'
import App from './App.vue'

const pinia = createPinia()
const app = createApp(App)

app.use(pinia)
app.mount('#app')
```

I use this code and my Pinia work is good

[my result in pinia store](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNDmD.png)